# Notification not running after AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been developing a website for a little bit now, and I've been stuck on this for quite a while. See, I have a normal PHP page for my index, and on that page there is a button for a registered user to log in. I have a JavaScript function that handles the request through AJAX and that in turn sends it to a PHP page, login.php. I've discovered that the function works, it logs me in, assigns my session variables as shown later in the PHP page, but does not display the notification I have set in place. I should also mention that the options for the `xmlhttp.responseText` are the only options available during registration. Except of course for admin, which will be altered in the database itself. One last thing, if I enter in incorrect details, the `xmlhttp.responseText = 'Wrong'` and then the notification appears as intended.

Code for JavaScript Function:

```
function login(name, pass) {
var xmlhttp;
var check = 0;
if(name == "") {
    alert("Please enter your username");
    check = 1;
}
if(pass == "") {
    alert("Please enter your password");
    check = 1;
}
if(check != 0) {
    return;
}
if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else { // Code for IE5, IE6
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;
        if(resp == "Wrong") {
            alert("The details you have entered are incorrect");
            return;
        }
        if(resp == "user") {
            alert("Welcome back!");
            return;
        }
        if(resp == "developer") {
            alert("Welcome back, developer!");
            return;
        }
        if(resp == "admin") {
            alert("Welcome back, Admin!");
            return
        }
    }
    if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 404) {
        alert("The login page was not found, please try again later");
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "login.php?name="+name+"&pass="+pass, true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Here is the PHP page, login.php:

```
<?php
include "base.php";
$username=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
$password=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['pass']));
$checkLogin=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = '".$username."' AND Password = '".$password."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($checkLogin) == 1) {
    $login=mysql_fetch_array($checkLogin);
    $_SESSION['ID'] = $login['ID'];
    $_SESSION['Username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['Email'] = $login['Email'];
    $_SESSION['First'] = $login['Fist'];
    $_SESSION['Last'] = $login['Last'];
    $_SESSION['Type'] = $login['Type'];
    echo $_SESSION['Type'];
} else {
    echo "Wrong";
}
?>
```

Comment: done any basic debugging, like `alert(resp)` outside of your `if()` sequence to see what really came back from the server? you've also forgotten to do `session_start()`. so all your session assignments are useless - they'll be lost the script exits.

Comment: I have another file that links this file and another with all my database information as well as my `session_start()`, I will try the `alert(resp)` now thanks

Comment: Thank you so much :D in my PHP code I referenced a column in my database called First as Fist x_x thank you a million times over!